# In journey builder add contacts to data extension when clicking

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I am using journey builder, and ideally want those users that click on a link within my email to be dropped into another data extension that can then be using as the audience for a new journey.

Is that possible?

Thanks
Danny

Answer (score 1):

Not directly.

What it sounds like you would want to do is to have an update contact activity right after the interaction split for click.  Have this update a field inside of the DE with a 'flag' of some sort to show the link was clicked. (e.g. have a field named 'Click' and update to 'Yes')

You then will want to create a SQL Query on that DE that will pull all the appropriate fields and then have a conditional (WHERE statement) that only pulls those that have 'Click' equal to 'Yes'. This will then be pushed to your new DE.

Sample SQL: `SELECT SubKey, EmailAddress, etc...  FROM yourJourneyDE WHERE Click = 'Yes'`

I would recommend setting the action to UPDATE (which allows for Add & Update options)

Then add this Query into a scheduled automation that runs hourly to add the new subscribers to your DE.

You can then have this be an 'automation entry event' inside your new journey if you want, or you can otherwise use this as your contact model for the second journey.

---

Alternatively if you are having issues with the interaction split (e.g. due to dynamic links) you can remove the need to edit the current Journey from this altogether and instead add a sql query to the automation.

1. I would recommend adding a unique alias to your URL.  e.g. `<a href="" alias="newJourneyLink1">` or some other unique flag.
2. Next I would query the _Click Dataview. e.g. `SELECT SubscriberKey FROM _Click Where LinkName = 'newJourneyLink1'`
3. I would then set a time limit on the query to help reduce turn time and to prevent potential duplicate records.  Something like `AND EventDate >= DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE())`
4. I would then ensure that it only pulls in the unique records with something like: `AND IsUnique = True`

As the query would run hourly, this would always add the most recent records only to your new DE. To ensure the rest of the above automation can function as it would with the interaction split and query mentioned above, you may need to either add a join to your original Journey DE or add a second query to bring those fields over. The run time of the automation may increase when using this method though.

Comment: Thank you for this, very handy to know. The difficulty I am having is that my links are all dynamically populated using AmpScript and are not showing up in the list of links under interaction split. Is this a common problem or more about the way we have set up the email?

Comment: For your solution, it might be better to instead of using the activity split - to replace this with an hourly SQL query to the _click dataview and utilize either a unique alias or a similar flag to differentiate these clicks from others.